# How to define a variables in Kubernetes's PrometheusRule

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

My current PrometheusRule at Kubernetes is implemented as follows: (note there is a hardcoded number 10000000000:

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  namespace: mytest
  labels:
    team: myteam
  name: myname
spec:
  groups:
  - name: mygroup
    rules:
    - alert: MemoryUsage
      annotations:
        message: MemoryUsage at ec2 {{ $labels.cluster_id }} is {{printf "%.2f" $value}}%.  Threshold is 80%.
      expr: 100 * memory_average{container="XXX"...} / 10000000000 > 80
      for: 20m
      labels:
        severity: warning
```

Question 1: How can I define a variable to replace the  hardcoded number 10 000 000 000? I.e. Where and how to define something like this in PromethusRole:
`max_memory=10 000 000 000` , and then replace the expr to something like this?

```
expr: 100 * memory_average{container="XXX"...} / var.max_memory > 80
```

Question2: I want the value of max_memory different for different clusters. In PromethusRole, how can I define the variable with the logic as below? Thank you!

```
if  {{ $labels.cluster_id }} == "ClusterA":
    max_memory = 10000000000
else If  {{ $labels.cluster_id }} == "ClusterB":
    max_memory = 7000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about `templatizing` your manifests. You will need a template system for this which will generate these YAMLs for you ***before*** you can apply them to your cluster.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, you can try [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), or [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) to begin with. These will allow you to create templates in the way you are describing, and when you generate your manifests, these values will be substituted and you will have ready manifests you can apply to your cluster.

For more advanced applications you can look into [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) template system, which is Python based. This is also the system `ansible` uses to generate the playbook manifests.

Comment: AT zer0: Thanks. I do not think kustomize and jinjja are the solution. the cluster_id in my original post does not mean k8s clusters or environments like staging/production, which I can create different setting based on template. (I have just rename cluster_id to ec2_name to avoid confusion), my purpose is to create memory usage alert rules for many EC2 nodes. Note each EC2 has different max_memory based on their name/type so I want to get memory usage of all EC2 based on conditions. How can I archive that?

Comment: Ah, and since the EC2 instances will be added/removed as the infrastructure lives, you want to templatize the `Alert` system to manage accordingly? Then your best course of action will be a custom controller. It will monitor the EC2 instances in your AWS account, and it will ensure that for each EC2 instance, an `AlertRule` is applied to your K8s cluster to monitor it. This is one of the best approaches that is used a lot in practice and we have it setup in our infrastructure as well.

Comment: AT zer0: Thanks. I do not think kustomize and jinjja are the solution. my understanding is, if I deploy on different environments like staging/production, then I can patch different setting based on kustomize templates. But the cluster_id in my original post does not mean environments or k8s clusters. It means redis cluster, etc. My purpose is to create memory usage alert rules for all redis clusters. Note each cluster has different max_mem based on their ids (see the if..then logic in my original post). And I want to calculate mem usage of them based on that. How to archive it?

Comment: You will require a custom controller to do this. As I've mentioned already. The controller will run in your cluster, monitor resources and insure `AlertRule` injection in your cluster as the state of the monitored objects changes.

Comment: AT zer0: see my latest comment please (stack overflow does not allow me to change comment within 5 minutes ). the rule is to alert redis cluster, not ec2 in fact. Thanks

Comment: Nothing really changes, except you will be monitoring your `redis-cluster` pods instead of `ec2` instances. You can identify them with a label that `redis` operator might put on them. Simply query the API server for all the pods and ensure `alert` rules are in place.

Comment: At zer0: I read several youtube this week in order to understand how to create custom controller  but still not able to understand. The use case and example sound complex. the setup looks unclear to me. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzoWSfvE2yA. https://medium.com/speechmatics/how-to-write-kubernetes-custom-controllers-in-go-8014c4a04235. Seems I need to write go language based code using k8s API lib? In fact I just want to write some if...then... logic. Do you happen to know some document about how to configure custom controller and how to write some hello-world level example? Thanks

Comment: Did this got resolved? I am stuck in the same problem, any pointers would help

Answer (score 0):

for Question 1: *How can I define a variable to replace the  hardcoded number 10 000 000 000? I.e. Where and how to define something like this in PromethusRole: max_memory=10 000 000 000 , and then replace the expr to something like this?*

You can use something like below (if you are using Helm charts and getting the values from your Values.yaml file)

`expr: 100 * memory_average{container="XXX"...} / var.max_memory > {{ .Values.memoryThresholdValue}}`

**Values.Yaml**

memoryThresholdValue : anyValue

Question2: *I want the value of max_memory different for different clusters. In PromethusRole, how can I define the variable with the logic as below? Thank you!*

Here also you can use {{ .Values.maxvalue}}, if you variable is defined in the helm template file the use something like below -

```
expr: max_over_time(reloader_last_reload_successful{namespace=~".+", ingress= {{ include "kube-prometheus-stack.operator.fullname" . }} }[5m]) == {{ .Values.nginxValue }}
```